# OR Condition orConditionGroup() i

Tags: database

i have some Problems with the OR Condition in the WHERE part. Here is my function:

```
public static function loademails(array $entry ) {
  $select = db_select('users_field_data', 'b');
  $select->fields('b', ['mail']);
  $select->leftJoin('tc', 'tc', 'tc.uid = b.uid');

  foreach ($entry as $field => $value) {
    if($value=="1")
        $select->orConditionGroup()->condition($field, $value);
  }

  //echo $select;
  drupal_set_message('select: '. $select,'warning');
  return $select->execute()->fetchAll();
}
```

With

```
$select->condition($field, $value);
```

it is working i got WHERE a=1 AND b=0, but i need an a=1 OR b=0. Also

```
 $group = $select->orConditionGroup();
 foreach
   if
     $group->condition($field, $value);
```

return an empty $group

how do i get an sql statement with where and or ?